Добавление входящего письма в таймлайн лида в Битрикс
Мне необходимо создавать лиды по входящим письмам в Crm Битрикс24 и в лид добавлять письмо аналогии с исходящими.
Агент (скрипт) работает по крону, проверяет входящую почту и создает лид.
С добавлением комментария к новому лиду все получилось, а с добавлением входящего письма не могу разобраться и найти в документации как связать.
Возможно ли добавить в таймлайн входящее письмо по аналогии как на скрине исходящее? Id письма есть.
Возможно кто-нибудь пнет в сторону нужной ссылки в доке

